# basic pyparsing : parsing expression using "and" and "or"

Tags: python, nested, pyparsing

I have been fighting to get pyparsing for hours now, even if what I want to do is basic.

I would like to parse expression based on "or" and "and".

Example that is working great:

```
s = "((True and True) or (False and (True or False)) or False)"
parens = pyparsing.nestedExpr( '(', ')', content=pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums) | ' or ' | " and " )
r = parens.parseString(s)[0]
print parens.parseString(s)[0]
```

which prints:

```
[['True', 'and', 'True'], 'or', ['False', 'and', ['True', 'or', 'False']], 'or', 'False']
```

Now, I would to the same, but instead of "True" and "False", use any possible string that contains neither " and " or " or "

I was expecting the following to work fine:

```
s = "( c>5 or (p==4 and c<4) )"
parens = pyparsing.nestedExpr( '(', ')', content=pyparsing.Word(' or ') | ' and ' )
print parens.parseString(s)[0]
```

but this throws an exception :

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ")" (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
```

I have been fighting quite a lot, mostly tryign to change the content, but no success.

Any idea ?

---- Note

I ended up using my own code rather than pyparsing. 
I guess the question nevertheless remains valid to for those still interesting in pyparsing.

Here the code I use now:

```
def parse(s,container):
    my_array = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i]!="(" and s[i]!=")":
            my_array.append(s[i])
            i+=1 
        elif s[i]=="(" :
            end_index = parse(s[i+1:],my_array)
            i += end_index+1
        elif s[i]==")":
            container.append(my_array)
            return i+1
    return my_array
```

example :

```
s = "(True and True) or (False and (True or False)) or False"
to_broaden = ("(",")")
for tb in to_broaden : s = s.replace(tb," "+tb+" ")
s = s.split()
print parse(s,[])
```

result :

```
[['True', 'and', 'True'], 'or', ['False', 'and', ['True', 'or', 'False']], 'or', 'False']
```

Comment: Visit the Examples page of the pyparsing wiki, see how this is done in SimpleBool.py.  Pyparsing will not only do the raw parsing, but will also recognize precedence of operations, `A OR B AND C` will actually parse as `(A OR (B AND C))`. This will greatly simplify your evaluation of this string later. Also, you are using `Word` when I think you mean `Literal` - and please leave off the leading and trailing spaces, pyparsing skips whitespace by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this solution is suitable:

```
s = "( c>5 or (p==4 and c<4) )"

#It's pyparsing.printables without ()
r = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
parens = pyparsing.nestedExpr( '(', ')',  content=pyparsing.Word(r))
res = parens.parseString(s)[0].asList()
print res#['c>5', 'or', ['p==4', 'and', 'c<4']]
```

Comment: it gives me "['c>5 or ', ['p==4 and c<4']]", which is a big step up, but still not quite right

Comment: Which output you are expected? ['c', '>', '5', 'or', ['p', '==', '4', 'and', 'c', '<', '4']] ?

Comment: sorry I did not make this clear. ['c>5','or',['p==4','and','c<4']]

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I made ​​a typo: the string 'r' must not contain spaces. I have edited the answer for convenience.